# Is there any Java Library to operate on unix config files like http.conf

Tags: java, linux, perl, config

There are very good Perl libraries (e.g. [Apache::Admin::Config](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache::Admin::Config)) to operate on traditional unix config files like httpd.conf. Anyone know if there is good Java libraries to do the similar task?

I know there is a c library called [Augeas](http://augeas.net/index.html) with Java binding. Has anyone used that before?

Thanks!

Comment: I know that (at least) Jetty is able to read .htaccess files which are basically Apache HTTPD configuration style. Maybe you could reuse their implementation.

Answer (score 6):

I worked (programatically, for a project) with a lot of config files  from many *nix projects like Apache's, Squid's, smtpd's, ldap's, PAM's etc. etc. I have come to realise there is deffinetly NOT a common format (grammar) but instead each project defines his own ad-hoc format and implements it's own custom parser. No common specification.

So the aproach on *nix projects [config files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file) si not "use the parser library" but rather "write your own parser".

There are however projects that try to stick to some sort of standard. Most common amog theese is the [.ini file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) (originated on OS/2 and windows) or [GConf file format](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/), for theese you may find readily [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190629/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-java) parsers.

Apache (read a-patch-e, as in made from many patches) is in the free-form class. It started with a `var value` format then, after a lot of "patching", added a warty-xmlish grammar for specifing scope and context of config vars.

- If you just tweak parts of the config file, probably your best approach would be to scan the file looking for your desired config vars and then work with the file locally.
- If however you need to config the whole file, better make a Java parser based on the C one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java library that I developed for my own purposes.

https://github.com/kkapelon/Apache-Httpd-conf-Reader

It is very early alpha. Use at your own risk. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java library that can be used to parse the Apache Server configuration. [ApacheConfParser](https://github.com/jrossi227/ApacheConfParser)

Comment: Is this only for apache http.conf parsing? what if I want to use the library to parse for example squid conf file?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an existing library for that purpose. You could, however, use [Augeas](http://augeas.net), a library made for editing configuration files. Unlike the solution you are searching for, however, you need to tell Augeas how to interpret the configuration file beforehand, which might take more time than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Augeas has Java bindings indeed, and it has an Httpd lens, too, so it is definitely an acceptable solution.

Answer (score -2):

Commons Configuration do manipulate configuration files.

Even it gives an option to save the manipulated properties in a new file also.

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("usergui.properties");
config.setProperty("colors.background", "#000000);
config.save("usergui.backup.properties);
```

Refer following link

http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#File-based_Configurations

Even, Apache Ant can also help you in manipulating the existing configuration files using your own PropertyHelper Implementation.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#propertyHelper

> **EDITED** after response in comments

Apache configuration do provide extensibility using bean Factory , you need to create the Apache config file httpd.conf domain class yourself , to make it working.

Defining the Apache modules in java you can have a look at Netloony source , service/apache/modules to have an idea on this.

http://netloony.sourceforge.net/userguide/intro.html

In netloony the config files values are presented in JTable, you need to use any configuration framework to persist it in file.

Hope this helps, I understand there is nothing out of Box in java presently to read apache conf files. I was trying to give a pointer where you can start with..

Comment: Thanks for information. But Apache Commons Configuration is not something I am looking for. This library can't manipulate apache http configration files which looks like:
<pre>
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 300
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
</IfModule>
...
</pre>