# Java library for reading Apache httpd configuration files (same as Perl's Config::General)

Tags: java, configuration, migration, apache

Is there a Java library that reads configuration files like those pseudo-XML used by Apache Http?
Example:

```
some_variable true

<myconf>
    order   Cache1
    order   Cache2

    <Cache>
        can_search  yes
        can_count   yes
    </Cache>

    <Cache2>
        can_search  yes
        can_count   yes
    </Cache2>
</myconf>

<details>

    host    192.168.10.1
    port    222

</details>
```

Basically is there a Java replacement for Perl module Config::General?
I need only to read the files, writing is not necessary.

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for my HTTPD java Web Application Administration as well!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any Java Library to operate on unix config files like http.conf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243686/is-there-any-java-library-to-operate-on-unix-config-files-like-http-conf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally created my own library for this.

https://github.com/kkapelon/Apache-Httpd-conf-Reader

Answer (score 1):

According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243686/is-there-any-java-library-to-operate-on-unix-config-files-like-http-conf) posted on SO, no Java library exists for the Apache configuration files.