# how to read a config file with sections using Java

Tags: java, configuration-files

Given a file containing this:

```
[upper]
a = A
b = B

[words]
1 = one
2 = two
```

How do I access these key/values with reference to their headers? Java's Properties() class only handles section-less files.

Comment: Duplciate of [How to parse INI in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190629/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the ini4j library (tutorial linked): http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

If you are a fan of the Apache Commons offerings, they have a library just for you: [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/). Commons Configuration reads many more formats other than just the .INI style files.