# Properties similar to .gitconfig

Tags: java, properties, configuration, config

This question is not specifically related Git. I want to create a properties/configuration file in Java with groups (similar to .gitconfig). For example, I want to group the properties as follows

[group1]
prop1=value1
prop2=value2

[group2]
prop1=value1
prop3=value3

Instead of

group1.prop1=value1
group1.prop2=value2
group2.prop1=value1
group2.prop3=value3

I researched internet thoroughly but didn't find anything related to grouping of properties. May be I am not searching with right keywords. Excuse me if I may have missed something online.

Thanks

Comment: Care to tell what's wrong in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same format used by the windows ["ini" files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).
There is a niche Java Library for that.

See: [What is the easiest way to parse an INI file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190629/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-java)