# Find string and append text in java text file

Tags: java, string, file, text, filewriter

Hi sorry for bad things.

this is a text file

```
[TESTRESULT]
testdate=5/16/2013
testtime=20:03:00
operator=Jacob Poulsen
test_no=62495
axles_tested=2
[AXLE1RESULT]
fric_l=38
fric_r=51
p0_l=0
p0_r=0
fl=280
fr=300
```

So i find issue for 
first find string ex:
second append text before [AXLE1RESULT]
Like this

```
[TESTRESULT]
testdate=5/16/2013
testtime=20:03:00
operator=Jacob Poulsen
test_no=62495
axles_tested=2
[SomeText]
Something=0
Something=0
Something=0
[AXLE1RESULT]
fric_l=38
fric_r=51
p0_l=0
p0_r=0
fl=280
fr=300
```

What should i do???

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are asking; but these files are formatted as Windows INI files. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190629/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-java will help (ini4j can read, parse, and write them, and will let you easily modify values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourfilename.txt"));
String dataRow=null;
string tempText="";
while ( (dataRow= br.readLine()) dataRow != null){
    if(dataRow.equalsIgnoreCase("[AXLE1RESULT]"){
        tempText+="[SomeText]";
        tempText+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
        tempText+="Something=0";
        tempText+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
        tempText+="Something=0";
        tempText+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
        tempText+="Something=0";
        tempText+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    tempText+=dataRow;
    tempText+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
}

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("yourfilename.txt");
writer.append(tempText);    
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: please use stringbuilder or stringbuffer if you are doing string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Better read it from one file and write it another file. If you want to append some text check for the occurrence and append it. Once you done with your process delete the original file.

Comment: I cannot write another file because another program using this file