# How to parse ini file with sections in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, ini

Here is a sample ini file:

```
[link#1]
alias=My Link 1
link=https://www.yandex.ru/

[link#2]
alias=My Link 2
link=https://mail.ru/

[link#3]
alias=My Link 3
link=http://point.md/ru/
```

I've seen how to parse it, but the keys are the same, and I need to get this into lets say `ArrayList<LinkObject>` . Does anyone know a good solution for this? Or shall we format the .ini file differently?

Comment: do you use a library for parsing ?

Comment: I didn't even start parsing. I've seen other posts like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190629/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-java but I couldn't find any library which can help me.

Comment: So are you looking for a library, or just trying to read this file?

Comment: Apache Commons has an INI parser; start there.

Comment: I am looking for a library. I think it wouldn't make sense to parse it on my own.
@DaveNewton thank you, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/configuration/HierarchicalINIConfiguration.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can suggest you [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/). This is small and very easy to use library. Just [download](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/download.html) files or include dependency into your maven config:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Now to load .ini file just do:

```
Wini ini = new Wini(new File("your file path"));
```

Examples of usage:

```
//output names of all sections    
Collection<Profile.Section> list = ini.values();
for(Profile.Section section : list){
    System.out.println(section.getName());
}
```

---

```
//fetch and output option value
String value = ini.fetch("link#1", "alias");
System.out.println(value);
```

---

```
//output keys of all options of one section
Profile.Section section = ini.get("link#1");
for(String key : section.keySet()){
   System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your Examples. I tried half an hour to read out an xml. And I still don't have a clue what todo with a Node object. But thanks to you I understand it right away