# How to retrieve group of values from property file by passing the key

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, java-9, java-11

I am trying to retrieve the group of values from property file based on the key.

myproerty.properties

```
key=1
name=adam
place=USA
address=Michigan

Key=2
name=umesh
place=india
address=bengaluru
```

I want to retrieve values of that particular key values.

Earlier i tried using the below method but it doesnt differentiate key.

```
myProperties = new Properties();
myProperties.load(HelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("/myproerty.properties")); 
name=myProperties.getProperty("adam");
```

but how do we retrieve group of values based on the key

Comment: You're not passinf a key but a value. Also this is unclear what your problem is

Comment: if i am passing 1, i should be able to get name=adam
place=USA
address=Michigan

Comment: This is not possible with the standard `Properties` class in the JDK.

Comment: That is not the way it works. This is a list of key/value separated with a '=', pass `key` get 1, pass `name` get adam

Comment: This is not how properties file works in Java. For your requirement use a database table  instead and fetch all properties using a primary key.

Comment: Don’t tag a question with every Java version that comes into your mind. What kind of statement is this supposed to make?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to read your properties file as INI file. Take a look:

1. [How to parse ini file with sections in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637174/how-to-parse-ini-file-with-sections-in-java)
2. [What is the easiest way to parse an INI file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190629/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-java)

So, your file should look like that:

```
[key1]
name=adam
place=USA
address=Michigan

[Key2]
name=umesh
place=india
address=bengaluru
```

and use a library like [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) for parsing such ini files.