# Parsing error after '#' line in ini file

Tags: java, parsing, ini, ini4j

I have a locally stored `ini file` which I am trying to parse as follows:

```
Ini ini = new Ini(new File("path/to/file")); 
System.out.println(ini.get("header", "key"));
```

But I keep getting a *parse error exception message* pointing to the line after the comment line of the ini file (#). This is what my ini file looks like:

**File.ini**

```html
#Tue Oct 11 18:45:03 CST 2016
PVIDNO=PALMUS-00001
PVIDNo=SSI-1
Authentication=VALID
ModelNo=KD03816-B001
PALMUS-ID=73364
PV-ID=PALMUS-01
```

Comment: Where does class `Ini` come from? That is not a class from the Java standard library. Normally you would use class `Properties` to load files with this format.

Comment: @Jesper forgot to mention I use ini4j for this.

Comment: Check this out [Click Me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190633/1577167) Wish this could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same with `Properties`:

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 p.load(new FileInputStream("user.props"));
 System.out.println("user = " + p.getProperty("DBuser"));
 System.out.println("password = " + p.getProperty("DBpassword"));
 System.out.println("location = " + p.getProperty("DBlocation"));
```

where the .ini file is:

```
# this a comment
! this a comment too
DBuser=anonymous
DBpassword=&8djsx
DBlocation=bigone
```

Comment: Where do I call or initiate the ini file though? Sorry. Newbie here.

Comment: p.load() method.
p.load(new FileInputStream("user.props"));

Answer (score 2):

You are using **some** class *Ini* that comes from who-knows-where; and that Ini-File parser simply doesn't like .ini files that contain "# comment" entries.

So, your options are basically:

1. I forgot about that first, but maybe the "best" option: don't use "ini" files; but change to "property" files; which are a much more "natural" choice for Java applications. "Built-in" support for them; and hey, "# comments" work out of the box.
2. If *Ini* is "your own code"; then you make your own code accept such comments
3. If *Ini* is coming from some library, then you check if that library allows to influence the parsing process to allow for such comments.

If the library doesn't allow for such special handling, you have another two options:

1. Look out for some other 3rd party library to parse your files
2. "Talk" to the people providing the library you are currently using and convince them to somehow make their library work for you.

Comment: I've checked the library and it does allow # comments. Will try what you said about changing it to property though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Properties?

Creating Config:

Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;

```
try {
        SaveSucessful = true;
    output = new FileOutputStream("config.jar");

    // set the properties value
    prop.setProperty("PVIDNO", "PALMUS-00001");

    // save properties to project root folder
    prop.store(output, null);

} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Reading Config:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
            LoadSucessful = true;
        input = new FileInputStream("config.jar");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        PlayerName = prop.getProperty("PVIDNO");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This should work perfectly.

Comment: You're using the `.jar` extension? Seriously?

Comment: Will try using Properties. Not quite sure about the .jar though.

Comment: Use any extension you feel like, .jar is just an example that I used.

Comment: -Kylie Irwin you can click on the check mark to mark the answer that works for you in case you didn't know.